# How to prevent Google translate Api from converting "\n" , "\" and "/"

Tags: php, google-translate

I'm trying to translate strings from JSON throw PHP.
This strings contains `\n`, `\`, `/` .
After translation this character disapears or extra spaces will be added, it depends on the position of this chars.

Example:

`red\ncars` => `voitures \ nrouges`

`red\n cars` => `voitures rouges`

`red/cars` => `rouge / voitures`

...

I need to keep this chars like this

`red\ncars` => `voiture\nrouge`

`red\n cars` => `voiture\n rouge`

`red/cars` => `rouge/voitures`

...

```
$apiKey = 'xxx';
$source = 'en';
$target = 'fr'; 
$original_text = "voiture\nrouges";                 
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($original_text) . '&source='.$source.'&target='.$target;
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handle);                 
$responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($handle);            
$translated_text = $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];   
echo $translated_text ;
```

How can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem \n was \ n after translation.
Some suggested to add "format" : "text" in the request but it didn't help.
When I decoded the JSON response it crashed due the \ .

Before I decoded the response I did:
translatedText = translatedText.replaceAll("\ n", "\n");  // Dart

Hmmm.... panic solution that has been in service for some time now